# How is it that the Identifier is not found? Could someone explain?

Tags: c++, function, variables, identifier

I'm very new to programming, I'm learning C++ and I came across a program I thought to try a certain way, with multiple functions so that I can understand and get more practice.

The program in just suppose to take the average of 5 numbers, that's the assignment, I know there is an easier way but I want to practice with making function and passing variables.
The professor also recommended it I do it this way for extra credit.

here is what I have.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

float num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;

float main() {

    cout << "Basic Average Calculator" << endl;
    cout << "Plaese Input your list of 5 numbers Please place a space after EACH number: " << endl;
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5;
    cout << "Your Average is: " << average(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
    return 0;
}

float average(float a, float b, float c, float d, float e) {
    a = num1, num2 = b, num3 = c, num4 = d, num5 = e;

    float total = (a + b + c + d + e)/5;

    return total;
}
```

This code does not work, and I don't know why being that when I typed it I got no syntax errors on Visual Studios, I feel the logic is correct?

I get an "Identifier not found" error on the average() function??

Could someone with experience please help me??

Comment: Your compiler tells you *which* identifier isn't found. All you have to do is fix that. Also `main()` should return `int`, not `float`.

Comment: It was the average() function however, I don't how to properly identify it?

Comment: You must declare identifiers before using them

Comment: `a = num1, num2 = b, num3 = c, num4 = d, num5 = e;` -- did you *really* mean `num5 = e` at the end or did you get that the wrong way around? It's weird that you call `average(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5)` and then manually re-assign each variable inside `average`.

Comment: It is also a good idea to avoid global variables

Answer (score 2):

Single-pass compilation: Identifiers have to be *declared* before they are used.

```
void f() { g(); }
void g() {}
```

is illegal. You can fix this with a forward declaration:

```
void g();  // note the ;

void f() { g(); }  // legal
void g() {}
```

In your case, move `average` to before `main` or add

```
float average(float a, float b, float c, float d, float e);
```

somewhere before `main`.

--- Edit ---

This line of code looks fishy:

```
    a = num1, num2 = b, num3 = c, num4 = d, num5 = e;
                                            ^^^^^^^^
```

Assuming this is supposed to be

```
    a = num1, num2 = b, num3 = c, num4 = d, e = num5;
```

then there appears to be no reason to have this function take arguments in the first place.

You could change your code to be:

```
float average()
{
    return (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5) / 5;
}

int main()
{
    ...
    cout << "Your Average is: " << average();
    ...
}
```

or

```
float average(float a, float b, float c, float d, float e)
{
    return (a + b + c + d + e) / 5;
}

int main()
{
    ...
    cout << "Your Average is: " << average(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow!! thank you very much! It worked, thank you for the clarification. I've written other programs where the functions would come after the main(), and they still worked? Is this a special case?

Comment: @VictorMartins maybe they were C89 programs, and/or caused undefined behaviour which went unnoticed

Comment: @VictorMartins Not a special case, perhaps you were compiling with non-standard options. Also, see my edit with some additional notes on the code.

Comment: @kfsone Thank you very much, I see, I also see what you did there, I can also just create a function and make it return a value with passing it variables! That's awesome thank you very much!